# "Take(away) on something" or "Take(away) from something"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am wondering which preposition works in the following examples?

**First scenario:**

Please imagine a beggar who is looking at you in a very emotional way. What is your take(away) ........ his behavior?
Yes, he wants you to help him.

a. on 
b. from

**Second scenario:**

Sara had said that she would help me anytime I need. I'm flat broke this month and have spent all my salary. Yesterday, I came up to Sarah and asked her for money. She just looked at me and said she would lend me that money the next week; while I had emphasized that I have to clear a check after two days.
So, what do you take(away)......this matter?
I think she just didn't want to lend me that amount.

a. on 
b. from

I think in both scenarios, both of the prepositions work properly, though I am not sure what would be your native choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common phrase "your take on X" means your opinion about X, or your interpretation of X or your belief about X. It can mean any of these related things.

The phrase "Your takeaway from Y" means the conclusion you draw from the event or set of events Y, or possibly the moral or lesson that you derive from Y.

In these expressions "Take" pretty much always uses "from" as a preposition, and is normally used for a conclusion or belief about or analysis of X. "takeaway" normally uses the preposition "from" and refers to some sort of summary or result of Y.

In many cases either phrase can be used, although some rewriting or rephrasing may be needed to keep the resulting sentence natural.

In the question's first scenario either could be used, but I think "take" is more natural.

In the second sacenario,  one could write "what do you takeaway from this matter?" or, better, "what is your takeaway from this matter?" orm in my view still better,  "what is your take on this matter?"

The expression "your take on" uses "take" as a noun. One could say "what do you take from that" using take as a verb, but I think that would be less common. "takeaway" in this construction is always a noun. When take is used as a noun here it is more natural to use it with "on" not "from". "takeaway" should, I think, always be used with "from". They are different words, with different although related meanings.

**Adapted from responses to comments**:

The forms  "what do you take on his behavior" or "what do you take on this matter" would both seem unnatural to the point of being simply wrong to me. Both seem to be using a verb form of "take" in a construction that calls for a noun.

The expression "your take on" uses "take" as a noun. One could say "what do you take from that" using take as a verb, but I think that would be less common. "takeaway" in this construction is always a noun. When take is used as a noun here it is more natural to use it with "on" not "from". "takeaway" should, I think, always be used with "from". They are different words, with different although related meanings

I would not say: "what do you take away from this matter" or in general "what do you take from X" to mean "what is your conclusion about X" or "what is your onion about X". I can't quite say it is wrong, but it seems to me quite unnatural in US English and I think in UK English as well.   I would think that a non-native speaker had misunderstood the noun "takeaway" which is used in a metaphorical sense in such a construction. (I am not sure if this is natural in other varieties of English such as the Indian.)

Comment: summary* and not summery

Comment: @Dhanishtha  Thanks, typo fixed

Comment: Well @David Siegel do you man that "take" works better both as a noun and verb and in both scenarios "from" is more natural-sounding?

Comment: #A-friend The expression "your take on" uses "take" as a noun. One could say "what do you take from that" using take as a verb, but I think that would be less common. "takeaway" in this construction is always a noun. When take is used as a noun here it is more natural to use it with "on" not "from". "takeaway" should, I think, always be used with "from". They are different words, with different although related meanings.

Comment: Well, accordingly for both cases "take on" seems to fit better in your view. But if I'm mot mistaken, you mean that the verbal form of "take on something" is a bit uncommon! So we cannot normally say: "what do you take on his behavior" or "what do you take on this matter"  in these cases. Right?

Comment: @A-friend In this sort of construction, yes. Both of those would seem unnatural to the point of being simply wrong to me. Now in a construction such as "I am going to take on a new job this year" "take on" is used as a verb in a very natural way. Also "I am going top take a chance  on this." or "I saw him take the coin" are correct and natural uses of "take" as a verb. So is "Take five" meaning "have a five minute break". Those are very different senses of "take".

Comment: And finally, I am quite sure that we can say: "what do you **take away from** this matter / his behavior / etc. as a substitute for the simple verb "take" which cannot stand alone in this sense. Do you confirm @David Siegel?

Comment: @A-friend  see modified answer above.